# Authenticate in Microsoft Graph API programmatically (Python) with my own username and password?

Tags: python, azure, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have an Excel (.xlsx) file in my Office 365 (Sharepoint Online). And I want to use Python to programmatically access (read and write the cells in the worksheets) the Excel file. It seems that Microsoft Graph is the right API to do it.

But I'm confused about how to authenticate with the Microsoft Graph API. It seems to need to register some kind of application in Azure AD and need the approval of my Azure AD admin. And when it gets to run, it uses the OAuth: pop up a window, let the user to login, then click the approve button.

The Python script I'm developing will be only used by myself. So I'd like to avoid OAuth because it is for multiple users. I don't need to support multiple users. And OAuth requires the user's consent in the UI. But what I want is a background authentication without any UI interaction.

So my question is **how to authenticate with Microsoft Graph API programmatically in Python with my own Office 365 account (a Email username and a password)?** Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the [Microsoft Graph API Connect Sample for Python](https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/5989).  I recommend following their example, getting it working, then try to change it for your own needs.

At the bottom of the page, they also give information on how to reach them here on StackOverflow.

Hope it helps,

J